# How to transform log(a)/2 into log(sqrt(a))?

Tags: maxima

I tried `logcontract(log(a)/2)` but it left the expression unchanged. How would I get Maxima to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately there is no satisfactory way to accomplish that.

Maxima's simplification rules only work in one direction. Given an identity, e.g. f(a) = g(a), Maxima implements either f(a) --> g(a) or g(a) --> f(a). There isn't a way to switch from one to the other.

Given a rule f(a) --> g(a), it is possible to disable it, but it is clumsy. Let me know if you want to go down that road.

Comment: Could you elaborate? It is not clear to me how your general comment apply to my case (my own ignorance for sure!)

Comment: Maxima converts sqrt(a) to a^(1/2) and log(a^(1/2)) to log(a)/2. What I mean is that it's more or less impossible to convince Maxima to go the other way.

Comment: Too bad. My problem stemmed from the need to transform log(a)/2 - log(b)/2 because sqrt(a/b) can be further simplified with the particular expressions of a and b I have...

Comment: Hmm. I see `logcontract(log(a)/2 - log(b)/2)` has no effect, probably Maxima doesn't see the difference of logs there. But `ratsimp(log(a)/2 - log(b)/2)` yields `-(log(b) - log(a))/2` and then `logcontract(%)` yields `log(a/b)/2`. Maybe that's close enough to be helpful.